# Improve loops performance to find the nth smallest integer in very large arrays

Tags: arrays, performance, sorting, processing-efficiency

I need to find the nth smallest integer (`n`) in the array (`arr`). It's an assignment on Codewars, so if someone could help me with hints rather than with a solution would be a lot appreciated. The code I wrote works perfectly, but times out when handling huge lists (of 1 million elements), so I have to improve its efficiency. I used while instead of for, and I changed the for from increasing to decreasing without noticeable difference. It's not the first time I struggle with code efficiency on Codewars, so I would really like to learn how to deal with this.
This is the kata https://www.codewars.com/kata/the-nth-smallest-integer/train/javascript , thanks for the help!

```
function nthSmallest(arr, n) {
    var b = [];
    var len = arr.length

    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (b.indexOf(arr[i]) === -1) {
            b.push(arr[i]);
        }
    }

    if (n > b.length) {
        return -1;
    }


  return b.sort(function(a, b) {return a - b;})[n - 1];
}

    nthSmallest([455555, 455555, 2222222, 2222223, 3333333, 9879799, 
79977979, 79977979, 79977979, 79977979,79977979,
79977979,   79977979,79977979,],3); // returns '2222223', the 3rd smallest integer
```

Comment: I would take a look at min-heap data structure. After building it you can get n times min element from it. Do not know this algorithm's time complexity though, needs further analysis

Comment: If you want to improve your current algorithm i would start from `if (b.indexOf(arr[i]) === -1) {` - it is very inefficient. On each iteration in worst case you have to go through current size of `b` minus 1. Using simple calculations you can show that in worst case building up array of unique numbers `b` this way  takes `O(n^2)`. You can improve it by using hashset to check for duplicates.